# Rotate single screen in Navigation Controller and TabBar

Tags: iphone, ios, rotation

I have a Navigation Controller and TabBar. I would like to know how the iPod app handles allowing only the play screen to rotate. I have tried to replicate this on iOS 4.2, and if that one screen rotates to landscape and you navigate back, the old screen is too. This is undesired... is there anyway to make the 2nd screen in rotate while not causing the rest of the screens or any of the TabBars view controllers elsewhere do so?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure your rotatable view returns YES in shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: method of UIViewController.
2. Make sure your non rotatable view returns NO in shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: method of UIViewController.
3. Subclass UITabBarController, override shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: and handle rotation here based on current UIViewController's shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: return value. You have to also check if current view controller is UINavigationController or not and if yes, you have to get current view controller from UINavigationController too.

It's not recommended to do this (I mean subclassing of UITabBarController), but UITabBarController forbids rotation if not all UIViewControllers do allow rotation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to state that in the 2nd screen the device orientation is only the desired screen orientation. So for every controller you create you need to implement `shouldautorotatetointerfaceorientation:`.